# AJAX returns variables null when updating data using Bootstrap Model in NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap model using ajax to update customer data. However, all variables return null even though there is information in the text boxes.

Customer.cs

```
public class Customer
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Customer ID")]
    public string? CID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Stored Procedure Update

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_UPDATE (@ID INTEGER, @CID NVARCHAR(100), @LastName NVARCHAR(100), @FirstName NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMERDB SET CID = @CID, LastName = @LastName, FirstName = @FirstName WHERE ID = @ID
END
GO
```

Update void is saved in CustomerDB.cs in folder Models

```
public void UpdateCustomer(Customer ctm)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBcon))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_UPDATE", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ctm.ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CID", ctm.CID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", ctm.LastName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", ctm.FirstName);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    CustomerDB objCustomer = new CustomerDB();
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Customer> lstctm = new List<Customer>();
        lstctm = objCustomer.GetAllCustomers().ToList();
        return View(lstctm);
    }

    public IActionResult Update(Customer ctmupdate)
    {
        objCustomer.UpdateCustomer(ctmupdate);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Ajax function

```
function Update() {  
    var res = validate();  
    if (res == false) {  
        return false;  
    }  
    var empObj = {  
        ID: $('#txtID').val(),
        CID: $('#txtCID').val(),
        LastName: $('#txtLastName').val(),
        FirstName: $('#txtFirstName').val(),
    };  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "/Customer/Update",  
        data: JSON.stringify(empObj),  
        type: "POST",  
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",  
        dataType: "json",  
        success: function (result) { 
            $('#txtCID').val("");  
            $('#txtLastName').val("");  
            $('#txtFirstName').val("");  
        },  
        error: function (errormessage) {  
            alert(errormessage.responseText);  
        }  
    });
}

function validate() {
    var isValid = true;
    if ($('#txtCID').val().trim() == "") {
        $('#txtCID').css('border-color', 'Red');
        isValid = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#txtCID').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    }
    if ($('#txtLastName').val().trim() == "") {
        $('#txtLastName').css('border-color', 'Red');
        isValid = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#txtLastName').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    }
    if ($('#txtFirstName').val().trim() == "") {
        $('#txtFirstName').css('border-color', 'Red');
        isValid = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#txtFirstName').css('border-color', 'lightgrey');
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Bootstrap Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="model-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLable">Edit Customer</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtID">ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtID" name="ID" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtCID">Customer ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCID" name="Customer ID" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtLastName" name="Last Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtFirstName" name="First Name" />
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Update();">Update</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

ID is the auto increment primary key which is auto incremented by SQL Server. The column ID will be hidden.

Comment: Can u post also the code for Customer in c#?

Comment: Post also the store procedure SP_UPDATE...

Comment: @DA I just updated them above.

Comment: Did you logged the empObj to the console right before sending with ajax. I did not understand where are the fields null, on controller after posting or something else? if the case is controller i will suggest something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update(Customer ctmupdate)
{
    objCustomer.UpdateCustomer(ctmupdate);
    //return View(); dont return view on ajax calls if you expect json or the another data!
    return Json(""); // or some data
}
```

Secondly if this not works try this without reversing my first suggestion:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "/Customer/Update",  
    data: empObj,  // i changed this line
    type: "POST",  
    //contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",  
    //dataType: "json",  
    success: function (result) { 
        $('#txtCID').val("");  
        $('#txtLastName').val("");  
        $('#txtFirstName').val("");  
    },  
    error: function (errormessage) {  
        alert(errormessage.responseText);  
    }  
});
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: I changed and tested the code you share, and i realized that you are sending with datatype json, actually you dont need it because .net automatically detects it and binding properties without using json type.

Another point is that, if you are sending data with ajax you may not need form tag in your code unless you serialize it and prevent default event.

It must work now with my changes, i tested it in my local.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but it's still not working.

Comment: I tested your codes and it works for me, can you try again with my changes?